# Params is not passing for the second time form the controller to view in Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5

I am building "comments" model for "post". Single profile will be having two tabs. Each tabs will be having ten posts. So , I am calling post using UUID (Unique Id).On first time, comments get posted and index page for comments is shown. But for the next time, without refreshing the page, comments getting posted via ajax but index page is not shown.

> My comments section in Posts/index is

```
<% @posts.each do |p| %>
  <% a = SecureRandom.uuid %>
  <i class="fa fa-comment post-comment coms" data-a="<%= a %>" 
    style="cursor:pointer;" data-postid="<%= p.id %>" data-class="<%= 
    p.class.to_s %>"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <%= p.comments.count  %>
  <div id="comments_post_<%= a %>"></div>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var comments_url = "<%= comments_path %>";
  $(".coms").click(function(e){ 
    var p_a = $(this).data("a");
    var c_type = $(this).data("class");
    var id = $(this).data("postid");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation()
    $("#comments_post_"+p_a).toggle(
      function(){($("#comments_post_"+p_a).load(comments_url+"?c_type="+c_type+"&id="+id+"&p_uuid="+p_a));}
      );
  });
```

In jquery, I am passing the UUID as p_uuid to the comments index action.

> comments/controller index action is

```
 def index
    @holder = params[:c_type].constantize.find(params[:id])
    @c_uuid = params[:p_uuid] unless params[:p_uuid].blank?
    render partial: "comments/index"
  end
```

I am assigning params[:p_uuid] to the @c_uuid.

> comments/index is

```
<div class="row postComment"">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2"><%= image_tag(current_user.image_url[:url], :class => "commentpic") rescue "" %></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
      <textarea id="commentText" class="annotation send-comm form-control" placeholder="Add a comment" 
        data-c-id="<%= @holder.id %>" data-c-type="<%= @holder.class.to_s %>" data-uuid="<%= @c_uuid %>"></textarea>
      <div class="hint">Press Shift + Enter for a new Line</div>
    </div>
  </div>

<script>
  var comments_url = "<%= comments_path %>";
  function postComment(context){
    var comment = $(context).val();
    var c_type = $(context).data("c-type");
    var c_id = $(context).data("c-id");
    var uuid=$(context).data("uuid");
    var commParams = {
      commentable_type: c_type, 
      commentable_id: c_id,
      body: comment
    }
    postData( comments_url, { comment: commParams }, function(data){
        $("#comments_"+"<%= @holder.class.to_s.downcase %>_<%= @c_uuid %>").load(comments_url+"?c_type=<%= @holder.class.to_s %>&id="+"<%= @holder.id %>");
      });
</script>
```

Actual problem is, I am posting first comment, its getting posted and index page is shown. But , for the second time the comments getting saved in database but its not getting shown on index or index not getting updated.

I checked with the console.log, `@c_uuid` from comments controller in passed to the comments/index for the first time, but its not available for the second time. Means, `@c_uuid` is nil for the second time.Please, help me in this.

Comment: You didn't pass the uuid in the url `$("#comments_"+"<%= @holder.class.to_s.downcase %>_<%= @c_uuid %>").load(comments_url+"?c_type=<%= @holder.class.to_s %>&id="+"<%= @holder.id %>");`

Comment: I have passed Sir, `<%= @c_uuid %>` in url

Comment: Not in the URL, that I can see... it's used in the function that fetches the data to send, but isn't in the actual URL (or data) sent... unless you can show us how.